# drupal 7 hook_form_form_id_alter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to hook into a form with ID equal to "block-admin-configure," `mymodule_form_block_admin_configure_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)` is not being triggered. When I use `mymodule_block_view_block_admin_configure_alter(&$data, $block)`, it works perfectly.

My goal is to add some additional configuration options to a regular drupal block.

Comment: I cleared the cache and now mymodule_block_view_block_admin_configure_alter is being called. But shouldn't mymodule_block_save ($delta, $edit) or mymodule_block_configure ($delta) work? when the block configuration form is submitted they are not being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hook_block_configure()` etc are only called in modules for blocks that *that* pareticular module defines in `hook_block_info()`, so if you're trying to hook into a block defined by another module you'll definitely have to user a `form_alter` function.

Just a note, hook implementations are cached in Drupal 7 so any time you declare a new hook you have to clear the caches before it'll get called.